# How do I horizontally center a set of 4 images inside a parent div with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I horizontally center a set of 4 images (one square block) inside a parent div with CSS? I also need the image block to occupy 100% of the screen vertically.

Thanks.

```
<div id="outer" style="width:100%">
  <div id="photoBox" style="inline-block">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `style="inline-block"` is invalid. Proper syntax is `style="display:inline-block"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`display: inline-block` instead of `inline-block` css stylesheet

[Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/McHUc/10/)